# Loading a resource with a generic base type from a ResourceDictionary

Tags: c#, wpf, generics, resourcedictionary

I tried to break down the problem to a minimum. Let's say we have a generic class that derives from `System.Windows.DependencyObject` and provides one generic `DependencyProperty`.

```
public class Generic<T> : DependencyObject
{
    public static readonly DependencyProperty ValueProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register("Value", typeof(T), typeof(Generic<T>));

    public T Value { get {…} set {…} }
}
```

Furthermore, we have two derived types.

```
public class GenericInt : Generic<int> { }

public class MyClass { }
public class GenericMyClass : Generic<MyClass> { }
```

All classes are in the same namespace and assembly. Now, I want to use both non-generic types in a `ResourceDictionary`.

```
<ResourceDictionary xmlns="…" xmlns:x="…" xmlns:my="clr-namespace:MyNamespace">
 <my:GenericInt x:Key="g1" Value="1" />
 <my:GenericMyClass x:Key="g2" Value="{x:Null}" />
</ResourceDictionary>
```

When I load `g1` from the ResourceDictionary everything is fine, but trying to access `g2` failes with a `System.NotImplementedException` with stack trace

> System.Windows.Baml2006.Baml2006SchemaContext.ResolveBamlType(System.Windows.Baml2006.Baml2006SchemaContext.BamlType,
>   short)
>     System.Windows.Baml2006.Baml2006SchemaContext.GetXamlType(short)
>     System.Windows.Baml2006.Baml2006SchemaContext.GetProperty(short,
>   System.Xaml.XamlType)
>     System.Windows.Baml2006.Baml2006Reader.Process_PropertyComplexStart()
>     System.Windows.Baml2006.Baml2006Reader.Process_OneBamlRecord()
>     System.Windows.Baml2006.Baml2006Reader.ReadObject(System.Windows.Baml2006.KeyRecord)
>     System.Windows.ResourceDictionary.CreateObject(System.Windows.Baml2006.KeyRecord)
>     System.Windows.ResourceDictionary.OnGettingValue(object, ref object,
>   out bool)
>     System.Windows.ResourceDictionary.OnGettingValuePrivate(object, ref
>   object, out bool)
>     System.Windows.ResourceDictionary.GetValueWithoutLock(object, out
>   bool)     System.Windows.ResourceDictionary.GetValue(object, out bool)
>     System.Windows.ResourceDictionary.this[object].get(object)

Having a look at decompiled source of topmost method `ResolveBamlType` I see

```
Type type = this.ResolveBamlTypeToType(bamlType);
if (!(type != null)) throw new NotImplementedException();
```

It seems to me that the Baml reader cannot resolve the type of the generic property, because it works with `int`. But since everything is in the same assembly, I do not know where to start.

Any help is appreciated.

### Edit

I access the resources in code.

```
var rd = new ResourceDictionary
{
    Source = new Uri(@"/MyAssembly;component/Sample/Resources.xaml", UriKind.Relative)
};

object g1 = rd["g1"];
object g2 = rd["g2"];
```

But the original problem arised during loading a `ControlTemplate`, which has the generic resource itself, from the `Generic.xaml` theme. Same problem there.

Comment: How do you access it?
Checked your code with this
BorderThickness="{Binding Resources[g2].Value}"
Expected result - empty thickness

Comment: And show full bit of this code
public T Value { get {…} set {…} }

Comment: Value property has default DependencyProperty implementation: get { return (T) GetValue(ValueProperty); }  set { SetValue(ValueProperty, value); }
I tried different ways of accessing the resource. Currently I instantiate the ResourceDictionary in code and using the dict["g2"] square bracket operator. {StaticResource} didn't work either.

Comment: This works perfectly for me. How does `MyClass` look like, or is it just empty as shown in the question? And how do you actually load the resources? Please show that code, too.

Comment: Maybe declaration order of these resources causes this problem?

Comment: MyClass is empty, exactly as posted. I added the way of accessing the resources in my post. Runtime Version is v4.0.30319, Target framework is .NET4. Maybe I should add that I load the assembly as UI plugin at application startup via Assembly.LoadFrom("path")

Comment: I tried a lot of different order/load scenarios, always with the same result.

Comment: Ok, the reflection seems to be the problem. I set up an empty WPF application referencing my assembly directly. Works without any problem. So what can cause the reader to not know my assembly and how can I tell him?